# AQGridview Not Calling Datasource Methods

Tags: iphone, xcode, aqgridview

I am trying to implement AQGridView based upon the ImageDemo in the /examples folder. I have a view controller with the following declaration:

```
@interface ImageDemoViewController : UIViewController <AQGridViewDelegate,   AQGridViewDataSource, ImageDemoCellChooserDelegate>
{
...
```

None of the datasource methods in my view controller such as

```
- (NSUInteger) numberOfItemsInGridView: (AQGridView *) aGridView
{
return ( [images count] );
}
```

are being called. Here is where I setup the gridview making my view controller the delegate for the gridview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];   
self.gridView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.gridView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.gridView.delegate = self;
self.gridView.dataSource = self;

images=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[images addObject:@"http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTOXAzFMoK441mcn9V0OemVe_dtAuCpGjBkLrv4rffyOjYIo45BEw"];
[self.gridView reloadData];
}
```

If I set a breakpoint on

```
[self.gridView reloadData];
```

the line is executed but reloadData method in AQGridView is not called. The only difference from the ImageDemo is I do not have a .xib file for the view controller. Have I forgotten to hook up something, resulting in the datasource methods not being called?

Answer (score 1):

If there's no XIB, then who's creating the gridView?  If it's never created, then it would be NIL, and you'd have the behavior you describe.  (If that's it, then just adding: 
`self.gridview = [AQGridView alloc] initWithFrame: ...];` should suffice.

Comment: The gridview is created programmatically in the view controller.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but have you checked with the debugger or NSLog that self.gridView  is a valid AQGridView at the point you're calling reloadData? There's no delegate concept at that point, just a straight method call. If it's valid, then there's no way that [x y] doesn't call the method y of object x.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try implementing this:

```
- (void)LoadSearch
{
    NSURL *test1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.4ddraws.com/search_iphone.asp"];
    NSURLRequest *test = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:test1];
    [web4D setScalesPageToFit:(YES)];
    [web4D loadRequest:test];

}
```

Comment: Sorry what does this answer have to do with the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  Solved by **replacing** the **view** with the AQGridView.
<strike>[self.view addSubview:self.gridView]</strike>

```
 self.view = self.gridView;
```

Full method:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.gridView = [[AQGridView alloc] init];
    self.gridView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.gridView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.gridView.delegate = self;
    self.gridView.dataSource = self;

    self.view = self.gridView;

    [self.gridView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I found the reload data part was the critical piece here.